# What is the format of coding the average in ms word vba? I'm new sorry Please be nice

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]

I have a project at my school and I need to calculate the average of all the grades, we're using ms word vba. I know the code is soo dumb but im new and young.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line

```
Dim average as Double
```

near the top, and change the assignment lines to use `CInt()`, e.g.

```
firstnumber = CInt(txtMath.Text)
```

and change the `average =` line to the following

```
average = (firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber + fourthNumber + fifthNumber + sixthNumber) / 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question, how do you put the average to the label? the name of the label btw is "labelAverage"; How do you code it? I'm in 8th grade too so im new, thanks

Comment: `labelAverage.Caption = "Average"`

Comment: Thanks but I mean, how do you put the average of the grades in a label that is name is "labelAverage". Sorry I wrote the sentence wrong:)

Comment: `labelAverage.Caption = average`